# Xamarin - update entry binding when unfocused

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, editor

Is there a way to make the binding update only when entry is unfocused? I've bound entry to slider and it is hard to enter a value in entry, because binding kicks in and replaces the text in entry (for instance user writes "1", which gets immediately replaced by "1.00" and user cannot write anymore)

I've tried to set up the binding in the following way, without success:

```
<Entry (...)
    Text="{Binding Depth, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource FloatToStringConverter}, UpdateSourceEventName=Unfocused}" />
```

Comment: I think you can make the Binding Mode to "OneWay", that way, the source (entry) updates the target (slider), and the target can't update the source

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code

```
<StackLayout Padding="10, 0">
    <Slider x:Name="slider"  WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="50" />

    <Entry  Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},
                                Mode=OneWay,   
                                Path=Value,
                                Converter={StaticResource FloatToStringConverter}}" />


</StackLayout>
```

Comment: This will no longer allow user to enter data via entry (slider won't move). Removing one part of the binding does not solve my problem - I want both to be updated on change, but slider only when entry loses focus (instead of immediately).

Comment: I am afraid that you could not implement it .